# Write json to a file in Haskell (with Text rather than [Char])

Tags: json, haskell

I'm trying to serialize an object into a JSON string and write it to a file.

In python, I'd do something like:

```
>>> meowmers = {"name" : "meowmers", "age" : 1}
>>> import json
>>> with open("myfile.json","wb") as f
    json.dump(meowmers, f)

$ cat myfile.json
{"age": 1, "name": "meowmers"}
```

I'm looking at this in Haskell

```
$ stack ghci

{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
:set -XOverloadedStrings

import GHC.Generics
import Data.Aeson as A
import Data.Text.Lazy as T
import Data.Text.Lazy.IO as I

:{
data Cat = Cat {
      name :: Text
    , age  :: Int
    } deriving Show
:}

let meowmers = Cat {name = "meowmers", age = 1}
writeFile "myfile.json" (encode meowmers)
```

Oh no!

```
*A T I GHC.Generics> I.writeFile "myfile2.json" (encode meowmers)

<interactive>:34:29:
    Couldn't match expected type ‘Text’
                with actual type ‘bytestring-0.10.6.0:Data.ByteString.Lazy.Internal.ByteString’
    In the second argument of ‘I.writeFile’, namely ‘(encode meowmers)’
    In the expression: I.writeFile "myfile2.json" (encode meowmers)
```

Two questions:

1. This appears to be a bytestring.  How can I work with that?
2. If that's not what I want to do, is there a Haskell json serialization solution using Text rather than String that is yet rather simple?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

So, to iron everything out (since most of the work has already been done). You actually have two problems:

1. You are mixing string types
2. You don't have an instance of `ToJSON` declared for `Cat`

Here is a working example that relies on recent versions of `aeson` and `text` (for me that is `aeson-1.0.0.0` and `text-1.2.2.1`.

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings, DeriveGeneric, DeriveAnyClass #-}

import GHC.Generics
import Data.Text.Lazy (Text)
import Data.Text.Lazy.IO as I
import Data.Aeson.Text (encodeToLazyText)
import Data.Aeson (ToJSON)

data Cat = Cat { name :: Text, age :: Int } deriving (Show, Generic, ToJSON)

meowmers = Cat { name = "meowmers", age = 1 }

main = I.writeFile "myfile.json" (encodeToLazyText meowmers)
```

As you can probably tell from the imports, I rely on `aeson` to convert between string types through `encodeToLazyText`. That deals with problem number 1.

Then, I use the language extension `DeriveGeneric` to get a `Generic` instance for `Cat`, and use that in conjunction with the extension `DeriveAnyClass` to get an instance of `ToJSON` for `Cat`. The magic of that instance is again [part of `aeson`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/aeson-1.0.0.0/docs/Data-Aeson-TH.html).

Running this, I get a new file `myfile.json` that contains `{"age":1,"name":"meowmers"}` in it.

Answer (score 8):

You can encode JSON to a lazy `Text` value directly using [Data.Aeson.Text.encodeToLazyText](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/aeson-1.0.0.0/docs/Data-Aeson-Text.html).

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveGeneric #-}

import Data.Aeson.Text (encodeToLazyText)

...

I.writeFile "myfile.json" (encodeToLazyText meowmers)
```

A `bytestring` is a type for binary data—not necessarily text. To represent textual data in a bytestring, you need to encode it with some encoding like UTF-8. Once you have a bytestring (encoded with UTF-8 or whatever format makes sense), you can write it to a file using `Data.ByteString` functions:

```
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy as BS

BS.writeFile "myfile.json" (encode meowmers)
```

To make this work you need to give your `Cat` type a `ToJSON` instance that specifies how to encode it in JSON. You can do this automatically with the `DeriveGeneric` extension:

```
data Cat = Cat { ... } deriving (Show, Generic)

instance ToJSON Cat
```

You can also do this manually if you need finer control over what the resulting JSON looks like.

Comment: Is there an easy way to get that version of Data.Aeson.Text?  Seems to break my packages:
--  Failure when adding dependencies:    
      aeson: needed (>=1.0.0.0), couldn't resolve its dependencies

Comment: And the second gives me:
```
*Main A BS GHC.Generics T I> BS.writeFile "myfile2.json" (encode meowmers)

<interactive>:23:30:
    Couldn't match expected type ‘BS.ByteString’
                with actual type ‘Data.ByteString.Lazy.Internal.ByteString’
    NB: ‘BS.ByteString’ is defined in ‘Data.ByteString.Internal’
        ‘Data.ByteString.Lazy.Internal.ByteString’
          is defined in ‘Data.ByteString.Lazy.Internal’
    In the second argument of ‘BS.writeFile’, namely
      ‘(encode meowmers)’
    In the expression: BS.writeFile "myfile2.json" (encode meowmers)
```

Comment: For the second solution, try changing the import to: `import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy as BS`

Comment: Thanks, again, @TikhonJelvis.  With that amendment, I'm getting:
```<interactive>:27:30:
    No instance for (ToJSON Cat) arising from a use of ‘encode’
    In the second argument of ‘BS.writeFile’, namely
      ‘(encode meowmers)’
```

Comment: Or with an explicit utf8 encoding:
``` Data.Text.Encoding> BS.writeFile "myfile2.json" (encodeUtf8 meowmers)

<interactive>:31:30:
    Couldn't match expected type ‘BS.ByteString’
                with actual type ‘Data.ByteString.Internal.ByteString’
```

Comment: I got aeson 1.0.0.0 installed, which contains the encodeToLazyText method in 1.  

```
<interactive>:68:1:
    No instance for (ToJSON Cat)
      arising from a use of ‘encodeToLazyText’
    In the expression: encodeToLazyText meowmers
    In an equation for ‘it’: it = encodeToLazyText meowmers
```

Comment: @Mittenchops: The `ToJSON` problem just means you need to make your type an instance of the `ToJSON` typeclass, to specify how it's encoded to JSON.

Comment: @Mittenchops: I added a bit of detail about how to do that to my answer.

Comment: Thank you, this was helpful.

Answer (score 3):

Rolling all the comments and answers into one (credit to the other folks here, please accept one of their answers).

1. Derive `Generic` and `ToJSON` (or manually write a `ToJSON` instance if you'd like).  This required a few more `LANGUAGE` pragmas.
2. Use either a newer version of `text` and `encodeToLazyText` OR use `Data.ByteString.Lazy.writeFile` to write out the bytestring.

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveGeneric #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveAnyClass #-}

import GHC.Generics
import Data.Aeson (encode,ToJSON(..))
import Data.Text.Lazy (Text)
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy as BS

data Cat = Cat { name :: Text
               , age  :: Int
               } deriving (Show,Generic,ToJSON)

main =
  do let meowmers = Cat {name = "meowmers", age = 1}
     BS.writeFile "myfile.json" (encode meowmers)
```

Resulting in:

```
tommd@HalfAndHalf /tmp% runhaskell so.hs
tommd@HalfAndHalf /tmp% cat myfile.json
{"age":1,"name":"meowmers"}
```

Comment: Thank you, this was helpful.